# Functional programming approach to repeated function application

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

> #### Control like `if..else` and `while`
>
> If \$f\$ is a numerical function and \$n\$ is a positive integer, then we can form the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> repeated application of \$f\$, which is defined to be the function whose value at \$x\$ is \$f(f(...(f(x))...))\$. For example, if \$f\$ adds 1 to its argument, then the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> repeated application of \$f\$ adds \$n\$. Write a function that takes as inputs a function \$f\$ and a positive integer \$n\$ and returns the function that computes the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> repeated application of \$f\$:
>
> ```
> def repeated(f, n):
>     """Return the function that computes the nth application of f.
>
>     f -- a function that takes one argument
>     n -- a positive integer
>
>     >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
>     625
>     >>> repeated(square, 4)(5)
>     152587890625
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

The solution is implemented using functional paradigm style, as shown below:

```
from operator import mul
from operator import pow

def repeated(f, n):
    """Return the function that computes the nth application of f.

    f -- a function that takes one argument
    n -- a positve integer

    >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
    625
    >>> repeated(cube, 2)(5)
    1953125
    """
    assert n > 0
    def apply_n_times(x):
        count = n
        next_acc = f(x)
        count = count - 1
        while count > 0:
            next_acc = f(next_acc)
            count = count - 1
        return next_acc
    return apply_n_times

def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)

def cube(x):
    return pow(x, 3)

print(repeated(square, 0)(2))
```

My questions:

1. If the code looks correct from a programming style perspective, can I further optimize this code written in function `repeated`?
2. Can the naming conventions and error handling be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have grasped the concept of higher-order functions.  To be more generalized, though, your `repeat` function should be able to handle `n = 0` correctly too.  That is, `repeat(square, 0)(5)` should return `5`.

However, your solution is not written in the functional style, due to the use of `count = count - 1`.  In fact, if you consider that such counting statements are forbidden in functional programming, you'll realize that iteration loops using `while` can't possibly be used in functional programming either.  You are then left with recursion as the only viable approach.  (Python isn't designed to do efficient or deep recursion, but as an academic exercise, we ignore such considerations.)

An exception is probably more appropriate than an assertion.  You should assert conditions that you *know* to be true, not ones that you *hope* to be true.

It is customary to combine the two imports into a single `import` statement.

```
from operator import mul, pow

def repeat(f, n):
    def apply_n_times(n):
        if n < 0:
            raise ValueError("Cannot apply a function %d times" % (n))
        elif n == 0:
            return lambda x: x
        else:
            return lambda x: apply_n_times(n - 1)(f(x))
    return apply_n_times(n)
```

---

Note that [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) is merely a handy way to define an unnamed function on the spot.  You could use explicitly named functions as well, but it would be less elegant.

```
def repeat(f, n):
    def identity(x):
        return x

    def apply_n_times(n):
        def recursive_apply(x):
            return apply_n_times(n - 1)(f(x))

        if n < 0:
            raise ValueError("Cannot apply a function %d times" % (n))
        elif n == 0:
            return identity
        else:
            return recursive_apply
    return apply_n_times(n)
```

Comment: If I would like to apply `square` one time, then I would say `repeat(square, 1)(5)` which gives the result `25`. If I would like to apply `square` zero times, Isn't that mean that user do not require `repeat` functionality?

Comment: Yes, I would interpret `repeat(any_function, 0)` as the identity function — that is, a function that just passes through the parameter as the result.

Comment: Your point in second para about `count`  and `while` is practically matching with the answer mentioned [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/272744/131582)

Comment: As we return implementation details to the user of repeat function; are we not breaking abstraction?

Answer (score 4):

In terms of the functional programming paradigm, I would suggest the following for `repeated`:

```
def repeated(f, n):
    """Return the function that computes the nth application of f.

    f -- a function that takes one argument
    n -- a positive integer

    >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
    625
    >>> repeated(cube, 2)(5)
    1953125
    """
    if n == 1:
        return f
    return lambda x: f(repeated(f, n-1)(x))
```

Note that, per the rule of thumb you have [previously discussed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272972/110531), each statement can be replaced with its result and the function still works correctly.

You could also simplify the imports:

```
from operator import mul, pow
```

In terms of naming conventions, `pylint` doesn't like single-character names, so perhaps `func` and `num` would be better than `f` and `n`/`x`, but in general you don't have a problem here.

In terms of error handling, you don't currently have any. I don't think that's a problem either, though - the docstrings explain what the inputs are supposed to be, and the user should *expect* errors/weird behaviour if they supply anything else!

Comment: sorry, am yet to learn lambda expression. Can I think of this recursive approach without lambda?

Comment: @overexchange you can also do it with a local `def`, i.e. `def _repeat(x): return f(repeated(f, n-1)(x)); return _repeat`. Any `lambda` can be replaced by a function.

Comment: Does these doc strings go in production code? I thought these doc strings are for the developers to perform Unit testing.

Comment: Yes, you should certainly have docstrings in production code, but not necessarily with [`doctests`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) (for example, if you auto generate API docs from the docstrings, you may not want them filled with tests). See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc, where I've put the tests in a separate directory to keep the production code tidy, but still included docstrings.

Answer (score 1):

This is odd:

> ```
> count = n
> next_acc = f(x)
> count = count - 1
> while count > 0:
>     next_acc = f(next_acc)
>     count = count - 1
> ```

Why assign `n` to `count` and then decrement it by 1 two lines later? Better to do it in one step.

And instead of `x = x - 1`, it's better to use `x -= 1`.

Putting these points together, the above code becomes:

```
next_acc = f(x)
count = n - 1
while count > 0:
    next_acc = f(next_acc)
    count -= 1
```

Actually you can go even further.
Notice that you're writing `f(...)` twice,
and in your original you did `count = count - 1` twice.
This suggests that probably it can be refactored to write these only once,
making the code shorter and simpler.
Thanks to the `assert n > 0` before the function definition,
this is equivalent to the original and simpler:

```
next_acc = x
count = n
while count > 0:
    next_acc = f(next_acc)
    count -= 1
```

Btw why is the variable called "next_acc". Perhaps `next_x` would be better.